# R- Using column.splice to define multiple ranges

Tags: r

I'm new to R. My program is erring when I try to select a specific number of columns using the colon (:) range syntax. What is the proper way to write this?

```
target <- read.table('/20130108.exome.targets.test.bed')
Bam <- c()

Bam[[1]] <- '/dataset/NA19761.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.MXL.exome.20120522.bam'
Bam[[2]] <- '/dataset/NA19774.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.MXL.exome.20120522.bam'
Bam[[3]] <- '/dataset/NA19770.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.MXL.exome.20120522.bam'
Bam[[4]] <- '/dataset/NA19651.mapped.ILLUMINA.bwa.MXL.exome.20120522.bam'

library(ExomeDepth)
ExomeCount <- getBamCounts(bed.frame = target, bam.files = Bam , include.chr=FALSE, referenceFasta ='./hs37d5.fa')
ExomeCount.dafr <- as(ExomeCount [,colnames(ExomeCount)],'data.frame')

    for(i in 1:4){
         if(i != 4 & i != 1){my.reference.set <- as.matrix(ExomeCount.dafr [,c(7:i+5,i+7:10)])}
    }
```

Comment: pretty sure your problem will be solved if you add () around i+5 and i+7 like so: `c(7:(i+5),(i+7):10)`. When i=1, these are the columns you will get: `7  6  8  9 10`

Comment: thanks. I will try it.